# Rails 5.1 use nested_attributes_for to update attributes on join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have three models in my API-only backend - `User`, `Game` and `Ownership`, which acts as a join table between users and games.

I have a service method that calls a remote API to get data on games the user owns. It then uses the data to add relevant games into the database, and update the user with extra data (game_count) and creates the relationships between user and his games. I'm able to accomplish this like so:

```
class GameService
  def self.getGamesForUser(user)
    # response hash gets populated here

    games = response[:games].map do |data|
      Game.find_or_create_by(app_id: data[:appid]) do |g|
        g.name = data[:name]
        g.icon = data[:img_icon_url]
        g.logo = data[:img_logo_url]
      end
    end

    user.update games: games, game_count: response[:game_count]
  end
end
```

So far, so good. While updating the user, the ownership associations between the user and the games are created automatically. But I would also like to add extra attributes to the join table at the same time (like playtime). I haven't been able to find a nice solution to this. I tried looking at `nested_attributes_for`, by adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :ownerships` to the game model, and calling

```
g.ownerships_attributes = [{
  playtime: data[:playtime_forever]
}]
```

before updating the user, but that seemed to have no effect whatsoever. I feel like there must be an elegant solution to this, I'm just not seeing it.

Here is the code for my models:

## User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :games, through: :ownerships
end
```

## Game.rb

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :owners, through: :ownerships, source: :user
end
```

## Ownership.rb

```
class Ownership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
end
```

Comment: you know the gem [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)?

Comment: @inye if I understand correctly, cocoon helps with handling nested forms. I don't have forms in this example nor do I need any - this is an API only backend

Comment: sorry I miss API-only. Do you permit the params in controllers?

Answer (score 0):

When iterating through games, save playtimes in a hash (with game.id as key)

```
games = response[:games].map do |data|
  playtimes = Hash.new
  game = Game.find_or_create_by(app_id: data[:appid]) do |g|
    g.name = data[:name]
    g.icon = data[:img_icon_url]
    g.logo = data[:img_logo_url]
  end
  #This is outside the find_or_create_by because it must be done for all games, not just the newly created.
  playtimes[game.id] = data[:playtime_forever]
end
```

Finnaly, after updating games, update playtimes in the join table:

```
user.ownerships.find_each do |own|
  own.update_attributes(:playtime => playtimes[:own.game_id])
end
```